# Intercept twitters completed tweet event with new api on client side

Tags: javascript, twitter, callback

Is there any way to intercept the twitter tweet event and get the evidence of completed action. 
We have already tried to use twitter events as

```
    twttr.events.bind(
  'tweet',
  function (event) {
    // Do something there
  }
);
```

but the event is fired on popup opening

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i've sent a question on "twittercommunity.com" and they answered me that the tweet event is fired on "tweet button".
They made this change in November 2015:

https://twittercommunity.com/t/tweet-event-not-fired-after-publishing/60834